# Response.Write - how do I get rid of the script now?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, response.write

I used Response.Write to write dynamic javascript into a page to test some values in code using an alert box (couldn't step through on a test machine using a build). I've reverted the code, Rebuilt, deleted all the temp data from IE and the alert still shows.

I implemented this through a recommendation (foolishly, apparently) and now I can't get rid it.

Can anyone tell me how to "undo" this?

Comment: View source, search for `alert` in the HTML source in your browser, and track it back to what is generating it.  Removing the lines of `Response.Write` should definitely remove the javascript, regardless of the browser cache.  You may still have some other test code in there that you've forgotten about, or maybe you didn't revert back far enough if you're using a source control system.

Comment: It's defintely reverted. It's all in one place and I manually deleted and committed code. I'll look into your other suggestion, though.

Comment: @mellamokb How do I trace it back to what is generating it? Looking at the mark-up in the browser, I see the scripts that were inserted but I don't know how to trace them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by restarting IIS (iisreset) to make sure IIS has dumped its cache. If that doesn't work and (you said IE was cleared) you can manually delete the ASP.NET precomiled temp files.

Comment: Doesn't rebuilding handle those temp files? I also tried restarting IIS and that didnt work

Comment: Rebuilding the app doesn't always have enough to replace the temp files IIS creates.

Comment: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\myapp.application are you talking about the files found there?

Comment: Yes. Those would be the ones to get rid of.